# Excel COM Interop - get_Range Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, com, interop

I am recieving this exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x800A03EC.

on this bit of code:

```
         foreach(Excel.Range rng in xlWorkSheet1.UsedRange.Cells)
            {       
                
                if (rng.Value2 != xlWorkSheet2.get_Range(rng,Type.Missing).Value2) //here
                {
...........
```

I'm basically trying to compare two excel files cell by cell but `get_range` seems to be giving me this error. Why?

Comment: FYI 0x800A03EC = ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be somewhat more specific in getting the range from xlWorkSheet2 by using the address property of rng.

Alternatively you can iterate through the rows and columns of the usedrange and provide the row and column in xlWorkSheet2.Cells[row, column].

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by doing xlWorkSheet2.get_Range(rng.get_Address(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing), Type.Missing).Value2)